# How to make a flask route for all pages except /static

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to make a flask route that routes to all pages except those in the /static directory

I tried this code:
`@app.route('/', defaults={'path': ''}) @app.route('/<path:path>') def catch_all(path): return 'You want path: %s' % path`
but it caused /static not to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to match any url except /static it would be easiest to define no routes at all but instead use a 404 Not Found error handler to house your code.

```
from werkzeug.exceptions import NotFound
from flask import request

@app.errorhandler(NotFound):
    path = request.path
    return 'You want path: %s' % path
```